# Kurtosis relation to error in variance estimate

Tags: variance, random-variable, standard-deviation, standard-error, kurtosis

For a normally distributed data, the std error of variance estimate is directly proportional to variance. However if the data has a very high kurtosis and is not normally distributed,  would a high kurtosis point to even higher standard error in the estimate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance. The formula given therein for the variance of the sample variance estimate shows how kurtosis directly affects the accuracy of the variance estimate, with higher kurtosis implying less accuracy of the variance estimate.

On the other hand, if you are using the wrong (normality-assuming) standard error formula (i.e., square root of the estimated variance of the sample variance when normality is assumed), then kurtosis will not affect the result, but the result itself will be wrong.