# A question about the variance of sample variance?

Tags: variance, sample, kurtosis

if I have negative kurtosis in my distribution (meaning negative exceeded kurtosis) - which indicates that the tails are lighter than normal distribution tails.

Does it also mean that I have more confidence in my assessment of the population variance (using the sample variance)?
Because with a negative kurtosis, I will also have a smaller variance of the sample variance.

Comment: Does rhe following answer your question?  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423343/kurtosis-relation-to-error-in-variance-estimate

Comment: not really, because in my situation I am talking about when I have a negative kurtosis (meaning less kurtosis than a normal distribution).

is my estimate of the variance in the population os more precise when my sample has been sampled from a distribution of a large negative kurtosis?

Comment: Look at the wikipedia link in my first link, the formula given there is valid also for negative excess kurtosis ...

Comment: Specifically, in the formula involving kurtosis $\kappa$, negative excess kurtosis corresponds to $\kappa < 3$.